# Download latest IntelliJ IDEA EAP

Tags: intellij-idea

I am having trouble downloading the latest IntelliJ IDEA EAP.

In the past, the latest EAP was available for download from https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Latest+builds but today it doesn't have the link to download the latest EAP.

[image]
Thanks.

Comment: The EAP program does not run all the time; the EAP for 2020.3 hasn't started yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on any link and you'll be able to download the latest build for the selected version.
Here is what you'll see if you scroll a bit after clicking:

[image: EAP download page]

You can also use the [Jetbrains toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/) to easily manage your versions and download the new EAP when it will be available

Answer (score 1):

Here is the direct link to the EAP

```
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion
```

or

```
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/download-thanks.html?type=eap,rc&platform=mac
```